# Access v-for current item from v-bind directive function call

Tags: vuejs2, v-for

I need to loop over some tasks objects with a v-for directive.

```
<div v-for="(currentTask, taskName) in step.tasks">
    <span>{{ currentTask.title }}</span>
    <button :class="getTaskButtonProp(currentTask, 'class')" :disabled="getTaskButtonProp(currentTask, 'disabled')">{{ getTaskButtonProp(currentTask, 'caption') }}</button>
</div>
```

The vue instance method involved:

```
// …
,methods: {
    getTaskButtonProp : function (task, key) {
        let out = tasksStatusDescriptor[task.status][key];
        // out variable manipulation …
        return out;
    }
}
```

The data involved:

[image]

Vue complains and says `ReferenceError: currentTask is not defined.`, as if v-bind directive parsing did not grant access to the current loop scope.

Did I miss something here ? Is there some sort of special syntax here ? Or did anyone already spot a workaround ? Thank you.

### EDIT

This code is perfectly fine. A missing attribute's ending double quote boundary, up in the dom tree, led to a set of errors that have now disappeared.

Comment: Do you use `currentTask` instead of `task` anywhere in your `getTaskButtonProp` method?

Comment: @thanksd thank you. No I don't `:/`

Comment: I put your code in a vue component and set `step.tasks` to `{ a: { title: 'foo' } }` and it gives no error. So I think, somewhere in your vue instance code, you are refering to `currentTask` by mistake.